# Can i share column space in ng2-smart-table and customize pagination?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have ng2-smart-table i want to share space of other column as column structure is independent in this table, i have two fields data in same column(i.e. fullname and notes), if notes are too longer so i want it to display in box and take space of other column, so i see whole table data properly attaching an image for refrence, i tried to search it but no luck.Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image]